# C++ inheritance for classes that depend on one another

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance

I am trying to design an abstract class in C++. It is called AbstractCurve and it has
AbstractPoint's on it that are made up of x and y coordinates which are AbstractFieldElements.
I want to inherit from this to make, for example, a PrimeCurve that has PrimePoints and
PrimeFieldElements. 
If I do something like this:

```
class AbstractPoint {
private:
    AbstractFieldElement* x_;
    AbstractFieldElement* y_;
};
```

How will I tell the compiler to make x_ and y_ be PrimeFieldElements when I create
the PrimePoint class?

Also, is there some better way to do this that I am missing?

Comment: Your question title doesn't seem to match the text of the question.

Comment: I also struggle with understanding the question itself...

Comment: You're right about the title. @cmaster what is confusing about the question?

Comment: Do you mean is it possible to inherit in more than one layer (where one class derived from another, and inside is a class derived from another class), or are you asking for "multiple inheritance" (where one class derives from more than one base class) within one class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the only difference between the classes is these datatypes, I would do something like this:

```
template <typename ElementType>
class Point {
private:
    ElementType* x_;
    ElementType* y_;
};
using AbstractPoint = Point<AbstractFieldElement>;
using PrimePoint = Point<PrimeFieldElement>;
```

If we take this to the next level up, we can keep going

```
template <typename ElementType>
class Curve {
private:
    using Point = Point<ElementType>;
    std::vector<Point> points_;
};
using AbstractCurve = Curve<AbstractFieldElement>;
using PrimeFieldCure = Curve<PrimeFieldElement>;
```

It is reasonable to use inheritance as you are suggesting to provide common behavior to a variety of curve/point types, but if the different types will use different internal data types, then templates are the way to go.

Comment: I think this is what I was looking for. What does the "using" keyword do?

Comment: `using` declares a template or type alias.  An alternative syntax that would work on older compilers is `typedef Point<AbstractFieldElement> AbstractPoint;`  You could get away with just using the template types directly, but giving them an alias allows you to use them with the names you're expecting and allow you to use shorter names.